# Using Line Breaks in Google Apps Script HTML Variables

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email, templating-engine

I'm trying to send an e-mail from Google Apps Script that uses variables. I have a template HTML set up with a "Header" and a "Message" variable. Whenever I pass html code to the "message" variable, it doesn't render as HTML but instead renders literally. I'd love to know how to get this working.

code.gs

```
function sendEmail() {
var fileNo = '12345';
HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTemplate');
emailHTML.header = "New File Opened";
emailHTML.message =
    'A new file has been opened. <br> File Information: <br>' +
    'File Number: ' + fileNo + '<br>';
MailApp.sendEmail(me@me.com, 'New File', "No HTML Client", {htmlBody: emailHTML.evaluate().getContent()});
};
```

emailTemplate.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align:center; font-family:Cambria;">
      <h2> <?= header ?> </h2>
      </div>
    <div style="background:#ececec; font-size:130%; color:black; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; padding:10px;">
      <?= message ?> <br> <br>
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Output Body:

```
"A new file has been opened. <br> File Information: <br>File Number: 12345<br>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a printing scriptlet. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets):

> *Printing scriptlets, which use the syntax `<?= ... ?>`, output the results of their code into the page using **contextual escaping**. Contextual escaping means that Apps Script keeps track of the output’s context on the page — inside an HTML attribute, inside a client-side script tag, or anywhere else — and automatically adds escape characters to protect against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.*

To make it work, use a force-printing scriptlet `<?!= ... ?>`.

As a side note, the email address should in quotes:

```
  MailApp.sendEmail('me@me.com', 'New File', 'No HTML Client', { htmlBody: emailHTML.evaluate().getContent() });
```

Comment: The e-mail was my mistake; that's actually a global variable. Sorry. But you nailed it with the force-printing scriptlet. I totally didn't understand that. Gave you the solution; if someone's looking at this and is confused, I needed to change the scriptlet on the HTML to: <?!= message ?>

HUGE thanks!